# How to update parse data after some period

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have xml http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=20070458&u=c and I want that when xml is updated my data also gets updated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried to periodicaly check this URL for changes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) especially regarding asking questions.

Comment: Well for that you need to hit url and parse received data at every 2 to 5 mins. Then, when your xml updated your data will also get updated

Comment: How to receive data every 60 second .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see this XML has `ttl` node, which tells that *Time To Live* is 60 seconds. So, you can periodically (once in a minute, according to the **TTL** value) check this URL and stay up to date.

Comment: You can parse an XML (using http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/parsing-xml-files/ tutorial) and get the value of ttl node.

Comment: And I just want to add, that you can specify the ttl value in your app as 60 seconds, considering that this is constant number (very likely the way it is).

Comment: But how to reload in 60 second .Thanks

Comment: You can see example of polling in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11452430/183431 answer.

Comment: Or you can use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) and start fetching process again in callback.

Comment: We know this but where to write this one so that run in background or it work .Thanks

Comment: Check out link to the answer in my previous comment. @fvwmer commented place, where you can insert XML retrieving code.

Answer (score 0):

Read this tutorial for [xmlparser](http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/parsing-xml-files/) and [NSXMLParser Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html). I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can poll on it.

```
static void timerHandler(CFRunLoopTimerRef timer, void *info)
{
    //request the xml here and compare it with the previous one
}

- (void)weatherMonitor
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    CFRunLoopTimerContext context = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    CFRunLoopTimerRef timer = CFRunLoopTimerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(), 1, 0, 0, timerHandler, &context);//use your own time interval
    CFRunLoopAddTimer(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), timer, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    CFRelease(timer);
    CFRunLoopRun();
    [pool drain];
}
```

Run weatherMonitor in a background thread.

Comment: Where to write to check timer .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Implement [Easy APNS](http://www.easyapns.com/) which will notify your app about any changes.
   And you may deliver xml data directly along the notification
   message, or you may launch a request to pull up xml as soon as you
   get notified.
2. Set a timer in your app that will launch requests to check for xml
   updates each 1-10-60 minutes, whatever.

Both have pros and cons, depending on your requirements and abilities. One thing is clear: you CANNOT receive data from exterior without sending requests, other than implementing Push Notifications. Implementing [Easy APNS](http://www.easyapns.com/) will provide your app with data even if the application is not running. On the other side, with the timer, will be the fastest/easiest way. You decide. Cheers!